# Nested arrays in normalizr schema

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I need to normalize this data so that I have both an array of  lists and another of todos.

```
const data = [ 
  { 
    _id: '1', 
    title: 'List1', 
    todos: [
      {
         _id: "11", 
         text: "Test1"
      }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    _id: '2', 
    title: 'List2', 
    todos: [
      {
         _id: "22", 
         text: "Test2"
      }
    ] 
  } 
];
```

Here's what I got:

```
const todo = new schema.Entity('todos',{},{ idAttribute: '_id'});
const list = new schema.Entity('lists',{todos:todo},{idAttribute: '_id'});
const normalizedData = normalize(data, list);
console.log(normalizedData);
```

I've been trying their examples but none of them seem to work for this data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's `redux` and `react`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the schema that `todos` is an array of `todo` and that your input data is an array:

```
const list = new schema.Entity('lists', { todos: [ todo ]}, { idAttribute: '_id' });
const normalizedData = normalize(data, [ list ]);
```

or

```
const list = new schema.Entity('lists', { todos: new schema.Array(todo) } , { idAttribute: '_id' });
const normalizedData = normalize(data, new schema.Array(list));
```